# Return first match for grouped Regex only

Tags: regex, regex-group

I've got a very long Regex which contains baby regexes which are piped and contained within parentheses. The very last field that I'm trying to extract is the SKU. However, the regex substitution value returns two matching values. I want to to return the first match only.

Here's the regex:

```
((WEIGHT\s?\(KG\)[\n\s\D\d]*?(?'weightkg'\d+)\.?(?'weightdecimal'\d+))|(information\((?'sku'\d\d\D\D.+?\-?\d+?\D+?)\)))
```

Here's the source data:

```
WEIGHT(KG)
Set (with Stand)    5.3Set (without Stand)  3.1
ACCESSORY
HDMI    YesUSB  Yes (type C)
COMPLIANCE INFORMATION
Dismantling information(24BL650C-B) 
Dismantling information(24BL650C-BA) 
EU Energy label 2019(24BL650C-B)
```

The substitution token `$sku` returns:

```
24BL650C-B24BL650C-BA
```

My first idea was to add a lazy quantifier at the end of the grouped regex so that it looks like this:

```
((?'sku'\d\d\D\D.+?\-?\d+?\D+?)\))?
```

However, this appears to indicate that I want to match either the group or null and therefore returns tons of null values.

Comment: You have an alternation `|` which means that you can match 2 patterns if requesting all matches..the weight one and the information one. Do you need that whole pattern? What do you mean by substitution token?

Comment: What is peculiar about the first match? Maybe you want to just consume all the rest after capturing the first SKU? Add `[\d\D]*` after `\)`. See https://regex101.com/r/MylWIF/1

Comment: I'm trying to pull information from specification sheets, but the order of the information from sheet to sheet is different, so having a single regexp that captures each required value sequentially doesn't work.

The first expression (weight) works fine, but the second expression captures both of the SKUs and concatenates them in the token. As a workaround I've used the section title as the word 'information' isn't unique:
``COMPLIANCE INFORMATION[\n\s\D\d]*?(?'sku'\d\d\D\D.+?\-?\d+?\D+?)\)``

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
((WEIGHT\s*\(KG\)[\D\d]*?(?'weightkg'\d+)\.?(?'weightdecimal'\d+))|(COMPLIANCE INFORMATION[^()]*\((?'sku'[^()]*)\)))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lO6GLx/1).

*Details*:

- `(` - Group 1 start:

  - `(WEIGHT\s*\(KG\)[\D\d]*?(?'weightkg'\d+)\.?(?'weightdecimal'\d+))` - Group 2: `WEIGHT`, zero or more whitespaces, `(KG)`, then any zero or more chars as few as possible, then Group 'weightkg' capturing one or more digits, then an optional dot, then Group 'weightdecimal' capturing one or more digits
- `|` - or

  - `(COMPLIANCE INFORMATION[^()]*\((?'sku'[^()]*)\))` - Group 5: `COMPLIANCE INFORMATION`, then any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`, then `(`, Group 'sku' capturing any zero or more chars other than parentheses, and then a `)` char
- `)` - Group 1 end.